# Python удаление метаданных у фотографий

Tags: python, файлы, метаданные

Мне необходимо удалить метаданные у фотографии, хранящейся на компьютере, как я могу это сделать?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Попробуйте [Это](https://www.rupython.com/python-exif-7871.html):

> Вы можете попробовать загрузить изображение с помощью Python Image Lirbary (PIL), а затем снова сохранить его в другом файле. Это должно удалить метаданные.

```py
 from PIL import Image
 image_file = open('image_file.jpeg') 
 image = Image.open(image_file) # next 3 lines strip exif 
 data = list(image.getdata()) 
 image_without_exif = Image.new(image.mode, image.size) 
 image_without_exif.putdata(data)
 image_without_exif.save('image_file_without_exif.jpeg')
```

Надеюсь, чем-то смог помочь :)

Comment: import Image неоходимо заменить на from PIL import Image. Так же image_file = open('image_file.jpeg') на image_file = open('image_file.jpg', mode="rb").

Answer (score 0):

> Вы можете попробовать загрузить изображение с помощью Python Image Lirbary (PIL), а затем снова сохранить его в другом файле. Это должно удалить метаданные.

```
from PIL import Image

image_file = open('image_file .jpg', mode="rb")
image = Image.open(image_file)  # next 3 lines strip exif
data = list(image.getdata())
image_without_exif = Image.new(image.mode, image.size)
image_without_exif.putdata(data)
image_without_exif.save('image_without_exif.jpg')
```